# Gauge group properties VS Particle properties

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

Let us say that, for simplicity, we are studying gauge theory over 4-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, and that the gauge group is $SU(3)$, which is probably the simplest non-abelian gauge group after $SU(2)$. $SU(3)$ is 8-dimensional. Does that mean it corresponds to 8 bosons? Also, the rank of $SU(3)$ is 2. Does that mean that 2 of these 8 bosons have different properties from the other 6?

More generally, how do properties of the gauge group translate into corresponding properties of the relevant particles?

Comment: Yes, for a gauge theory there is one gauge boson per generator, so 8 gluons. Rank 2 means there are two group invariants (Casimirs), and that, e.g. for the flavor SU(3) version of this group, there are two compatible observables (good quantum numbers, here, isospin and hypercharge.) Your text does not cover any of this?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you (once more). The thing is I don't have a textbook, and I am trying to learn some Physics on my own (when I have some time). My background is Geometry. Some references will be very welcome!

Comment: A decent SU(3) intro [WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)) might be this; for [gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory); perhaps section [69 of srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have read half of the WP page and it is indeed very informative. I will make sure to read section 69 of sredicki too. Thanks!

Comment: Sections 15.1-4  of [Peskin & Schroeder](https://www.scribd.com/doc/83347525/Peskin-M-Schroeder-D-an-Introduction-to-Quantum-Field-Theory-Perseus-1995-ISBN-0201503972-KA-600dpi-T-865s-PQft) are part of every particle physicist's background, so they might well fix the language for you, at the very least....

Comment: I would like to add one comment. I don't have access to Peskin and Schroeder by the way. But I had purchased Weinberg's 2 volumes, though hadn't got the chance to read them. I am reading parts of volume I, and I love it. It emphasizes general principles, such as symmetry, and I find it deeper than other expositions (though perhaps difficult as a "first book"), and perfect for curious minds.